# how to select the codes that are in the dates 2001 and 2002 in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, date

We will create a new table:

```
create table example

(
        code             varchar(3),
        date             timestamp,

CONSTRAINT pk_code PRIMARY KEY (code)
);
```

We will add the data in the table:

```
insert into example(code, date)
values('001','2001/02/12 19:00');
insert into example(code, date)
values('001','2002/05/22 14:00');
insert into example(code, date)
values('002','2001/01/10 20:00');
insert into example(code, date)
values('002','2001/11/11 22:00');
insert into example(code, date)
values('003','2001/06/17 23:00');
insert into example(code, date)
values('004','2002/05/03 15:00');
insert into example(code, date)
values('004','2001/08/01 23:00');
```

And de question is: how to select the codes that are in the dates 2001 and 2002?, ie the codes '001' and ' 004 '.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a inner join on the same table

```
select a.code from example  a
inner join example b on (a.code = b.code) 
where year(`a.date`)  = 2001 
and year(`b.date`) = 2002;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `BETWEEN` to set a timespan on the search

```
SELECT code FROM `table` WHERE (date BETWEEN '2001-01-01 14:15:55' AND '2002-12-31 23:00')
```